# Problema al realizar una animación con Batch

Tags: windows, batch

Quiero realizar una animacion con Batch en donde empiezan a caer caracteres de la pantalla, de la consola como si fuera una animación de "hackeo", pero me encuentro que a la hora de correr el programa y compilarlo, me da el error de > was unexpected at this time.

Este es mi codigo batch

```
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion

REM Definir los caracteres a utilizar en la animación
set "chars=ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ0123456789!@#$%^&*()_+-=[]{}|\:;"'<>,.?/"

REM Definir el número de filas y columnas de la pantalla
set "num_filas=25"
set "num_columnas=80"

REM Limpiar la pantalla
cls

REM Generar la animación
for /l %%i in (1,1,%num_filas%) do (
    REM Limpiar la fila actual
    for /l %%j in (1,1,%num_columnas%) do (
        echo.
    )

    REM Generar una nueva fila con caracteres aleatorios
    set "fila=!chars:~%random%,1!"
    for /l %%j in (2,1,%num_columnas%) do (
        set /a "rand=!random! %% 100"
        if !rand! lss 80 (
            call set "fila=!fila!%%chars:~!random!,1%%"
        ) else (
            set "fila=!fila! "
        )
    )

    REM Mostrar la fila actual
    echo !fila!
    timeout /t 0.1 > nul
)

REM Restaurar la configuración del entorno
endlocal
```

Espero me puedan ayudar.

Comment: `>` es un carácter especial, tienes que escaparlo

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Batch es horrendo y yo creo que contiene almas en pena. Dicho ésto y [siguendo esta respuesta](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16018942/236345), tienes que escapar ciertos carácteres usando *caret* (es decir, el sombrerito `^`):

```
^, &, <, >, |
```

Ejemplo: `echo a ^> b` para imprimir `a > b` en pantalla.

Comment: Gracias @alfabravo, concuerdo con tu opinion, es muy feo, pero muchas gracias igual